# Get count and sum on multiple conditions in a single sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to generate some user analytics in a stored procedure.

Here is the sql code:

```
SELECT count(*),SUM(n.credit)  from notifications n 
left join questions q on q.id = n.question_id
where n.user_id = u_id and q.question_level = 1 ;
```

The column `q.question_level` has three possible value => `1,2 and 3` Is there a way to get the separate count and sum values for the three levels in a single sql statement instead of separate sql statements as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT 
  count(*), 
  SUM(n.credit) AS totalCredit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN q.question_level = 1 THEN n.credit ELSE 0 END) as level1_sum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN q.question_level = 2 THEN n.credit ELSE 0 END) as level2_sum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN q.question_level = 3 THEN n.credit ELSE 0 END) as level3_sum,
  SUM(q.question_level = 1) as level1_count,
  SUM(q.question_level = 2) as level2_count,
  SUM(q.question_level = 3) as level3_count
from 
  notifications n 
left join questions q 
  on q.id = n.question_id
where 
  n.user_id = u_id
```

Comment: I wanted a count on both credit sum and question count sum. Combining your answer and juergen's would work exactly like I want it.

Comment: @VarunJain : You mean like this. I update it with juergend 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(n.credit)
FROM notifications n LEFT JOIN questions q ON q.id = n.question_id
WHERE n.user_id = u_id
GROUP BY q.question_level;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT
    count(*) total_count,
    SUM(n.credit) total_credit,
    SUM(q.question_level = 1) as level1_count,
    SUM(q.question_level = 2) as level2_count,
    SUM(q.question_level = 3) as level3_count,
    SUM(n.credit * (q.question_level = 1)) as level1_credit,
    SUM(n.credit * (q.question_level = 2)) as level2_credit,
    SUM(n.credit * (q.question_level = 3)) as level3_credit
from notifications n 
left join questions q on q.id = n.question_id
where n.user_id = u_id
```

Conveniently, booleans in mysql are `1` or `0`.